# 'Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.' in cpu tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I have been trying to get back into machine learning and AI and have recently run into an error when simply trying to import tensorflow. When importing it I get the following in my console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-d6579f534729>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have tried using this in both a python 3.6 anaconda environment in pycharm and just a system wide install in spyder, both of which threw this error. I got no errors during the pip installation as all went smoothly. I use windows 10 pro and use the cpu version of tensorflow. Any help would be much appreciated!